# Android ImageView Suitable for both mobile and Tab

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview

i am creating an app for both mobile and tablet. its working perfect in mobile. But, ImageView in Tablet is appearing same size as the mobile. How can set ImageView with respect to screen size? How is it possible to create app UI compatiable to both Mobile and Tablet. There is also a problem with Landscape view and Portrait view. Please Help...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_fish"
        android:minHeight="300sp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:background="@color/bright_foreground_material_dark"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ranklabel"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:drawableTint="@color/background_material_dark"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:background="@color/material_grey_100" />
    <View style="@style/Divider"
        android:background="#bab8b8" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:drawableTint="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:background="@color/material_grey_100" />
    <View style="@style/Divider"
        android:background="#bab8b8" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/number"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:drawableTint="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:background="@color/material_grey_100" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/callButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Read More"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
        android:minHeight="100dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I suggest to stick to one problem per question.
Also, where is that image in your code? What folder? Do you have different images per different DPIs?

Comment: make ImageView have relative size - use `Linearlayout` + `android:layout_weight`, or `match_parent`

Answer (score 1):

if your image is ic_fish,save as follows .

res/drawable-xhdpi - large (9"-10") tablets  ic_fish(150*150) as per your required

res/drawable-mhdpi - small (7"-8") tablets   ic_fish(100*100)  as per your required

res/drawable-hdpi - all other devices  ic_fish(50*50)  as per your required

you have to create three different layout as follows

res/layout-sw720dp - large (9"-10") tablets

res/layout-sw600dp - small (7"-8") tablets

res/layout - all other devices